# Plotting a large graph with million vertices in Python igraph

Tags: python, graph, plot, igraph

I am working on DBLP dataset( contains the metadata of over 1.8 million publications, written by over 1 million authors in several thousands of journals or conference proceedings series) which has following columns -

```
['id', 'title', 'authors', 'year', 'pub_venue', 'ref_id', 'ref_num', 'abstract']
```

After converting this data in to a dictionary of key having id and value having list of ids from ref_id column, I created a graph in python igraph.

```
b = {}
for row in list(res):
key = row['id']
if row['ref_id'] is not u'' or None:
    val = map(int, row['ref_id'].strip().split(";"))
    b[key]  = val
else:
    b[key]  = row['ref_id']

graph = Graph( edges = [(v,e) for v in b.keys() for e in b[v]])
```

This graph contains million vertices and to visualize the data before running community detection algorithm over it,  I am using plot function available in igraph -

```
layout = graph.layout("drl")
lot(graph ,layout = layout)
```

But it fails with memory error on my system with 8gb Ram. Is there any better way to achieve the same in python ?

Comment: Plotting a graph of this size usually doesn't make much sense - you would probably get a big hairball only. For instance, let's say that you want to create a plot of 1024 x 1024 pixels. That's roughly one million pixels, and you have one million authors, so you get one pixel to "spend" on each node in your graph, and you haven't even started drawing edges or labels. So, if you *really* want to plot this graph, chances are that you need to go beyond standard node-edge diagrams because they are simply not suited for graphs of this size.

Comment: @Tamás Thanks for your reply. Yeah it makes perfect sense, I think the better way would be to plot a sample of given data-set.

Comment: @khushi How did you achieve plot this kind of large graphs ? Actually, I am at the point which you were in before. I will investigate community detection algorithms on a produced graph by me (with adjacency matrix has 50k * 50k size). Did you document your job in Github or somewhere? Any suggestion to follow ? Thanks.